# Upgrade available after upgrading normal release to LTS

Tags: apt, upgrade

Just after upgrading my Xubuntu 13.10 to Xubuntu 14.04, I run the command:
`sudo apt-get dist-upgrade` and tell me that upgrade are available, and after do it again and again I get the same result after installing thus packages.
Note: all packages are really installed, is like to reinstall them every time

Comment: The steps to properly update (via command-line) are: **`sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade`**, followed by **`sudo apt-get dist-upgrade`**. *Try that, and report if there is still an issue.*

Comment: @david6 you can skip dist-upgrade if you do not have held packages with update. You can skip update if you are going to later run dist-upgrade. The commands sudo apt-get upgrade and sudo apt-get dist-upgrade usually do not both need to run. In addition, the OP is asking about upgrading not updating.

Comment: Don't necessarily agree. Skipping **`sudo apt-get update`** can confuse things, and he may be being confused by **MOTD** reminders for updates available.

Comment: How to fix that please?

Answer (score 2):

dist-upgrade does NOT upgrade the system.

From the apt-get man page:

> dist-upgrade
>
> In addition to performing the function of upgrade, this option also intelligently handles changing dependencies with new versions of packages; apt-get has a "smart" conflict resolution system, and it will attempt to upgrade the most important packages at the expense of less important ones, if necessary.

To upgrade , run `sudo updater`

Or to do so graphically, see http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/upgrade and https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UpgradeNotes

Comment: No I upgraded it be the command 'sudo update-manager -d', and atfer everything is done successful after rebooting I used 'sudo apt-get dist-upgrade' and I have that issues

Comment: The -d option is not necessary, and in fact should not be used. From the man page " -d, --devel-release
              Check if upgrading to the latest devel release is possible". You do not want to upgrade to the dev release ;) At any rate, post your commands and error messages.

Comment: this is result of 'lsb-release -a': 'No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description: Ubuntu 14.04 LTS
Release: 14.04
Codename: trusty
'

Comment: it appears the upgrade went well. What problem are you having ?

Comment: When I run 'sudo apt-get dist-upgrade' or 'sudo apt-get upgrade' I have 969 packages to by updated I thus packages are really updated, this is the problem

Comment: please post the command and exact output

Comment: I cannot post all output this is the last part of the command output `sudo apt-get dist-upgrade` `
  xfce4-screenshooter xfce4-taskmanager xfce4-whiskermenu-plugin xfce4-xkb-plugin xfsprogs
  xserver-xephyr xsltproc xubuntu-docs xubuntu-icon-theme xubuntu-restricted-addons
  xubuntu-wallpapers yelp yelp-tools yelp-xsl zeitgeist zeitgeist-datahub zenmap
1105 سيتم ترقيتها، 168 مثبتة حديثاً،  8 لإزالتها و 0 لم يتم ترقيتها.
1 غير مثبتة بالكامل أو مزالة.
بحاجة إلى جلب 35.5 Mب/1,269 Mب من الأرشيف.
After this operation, 867 MB of additional disk space will be used.
هل تريد الاستمرار؟ [Y/n`

Comment: The arabic text say 1105 to be updated, 8 to be removed 168 will still unchanged 1,269Mb to downloaded that's all

Comment: is there an option to type "y" or enter ? if so, what happens ?

Comment: When I type y or enter every packages will be installed without any problem, after that I re-run 'sudo apt-get dist-upgrade' I have the same output I like nothing is installed even if everything has pasts successfully

Comment: odd, try running `sudo apt-get clean` and `sudo apt-get autoclean` and then try again.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that I've made a partial upgrade so I got some Ubuntu 14.04 packages but not all, when I've finish All upgrades that remained I no longer have any issues now.
Thank you guys for your help.